# What's the most efficient algorithm to compute powers?

Tags: python-3.x, exponentiation

I'm simulating the RSA protocol for public and private key setup through Python 3 and I have to deal with huge exponents. Since the `pow(base,exp)` doesn't seem to run in a reasonable time I've been trying to use different algorithms, but for now none seems to work.

Which is the most efficient algorithm by now to do that?

Comment: Do a simple multiply with base and compute modulus by n in every iteration for (exp times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the binary powers of base modulo n by squaring the previous binary power e.g. base^2=base^1*base^1; base^4 = base^2*base^2

By binary I mean base^0, base^1, base^2, base^4, base^8 etc.

Then multiple the binary powers when the bit is set in the exponent.

E.g. exponent 9: base^9 = base^1 * base^8. 
All calculations are done in modulo n.

Find attached the pseudocode; I hope it is correct because it is untested;

```
//pseudocode
function myPower(base, exponent, n) {
    power = 1;
    binarypower = base;
    while(exponent>0) {
        if(exponent&1 != 0) {
            power = (binarypower * power) %n;
        }
        exponent = exponent>>1;
        if(exponent>0) {
            binarypower = (binarypower*binarypower)%n;
        }
    }
    return power;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the answer to your title is *unknown*. This problem is very hard, and you can read more about it [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation). In practice almost everyone uses [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), including Python's algorithm.

However in RSA you use *modular exponentiation*, and I expect that that's where you're going wrong. If you compute `pow(base, exp) % mod`, that's going to be very slow as the intermediate exponentiation gets huge. The trick is to reduce the exponentiation at every step, which is allowed because `a * b mod m == ((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m`. This is also already implemented in Python, by using the three-argument built-in `pow` function (which is **not** `math.pow`, just the builtin `pow`): `pow(base, exp, mod)`. This function is equivalent in result to `pow(base, exp) % mod`, but much, much faster for large exponents.

Finally, for very large computations modulo a fixed modulus with a lot of multiplications, it can be beneficial to put your numbers in Montgomery form and use [Montgomery reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication). This is somewhat more advanced number theory though, and you shouldn't need this.

Comment: Orip, i couldn't find any info on how much speed difference can be acheived using the Montgomery reduction, would you happen to know, i'm interested in implementing it if it's substantial